# How to auto tap a button inside webview and how to autofill a form inside webview

Tags: ios, wkwebview, xcode9

Need help on ios webview 
I am trying to autofill a form located on any website can get path by ID or Xpath.
same with button want to know how to autotap send button after filling a form located on any website can get buttons xpath/ID

In selenium it was simple and easy dont know how to dive into webview looked everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You use the javascript bridge to perform operations on elements using js. For example to tap on a button:

```
let jsString = "document.getElementById('myButtonID').click()"
myWebView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: { result,error in
     print(result);
})
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is used for getting answers to your questions from random people without having to contact them privately (like email). What more help do you need?

Comment: ok 
I made a UI of a form(name, address, zip etc) I want to save form data in app offline 
use the form data to autofill